# React & SCSS - Print 2 different Pages with 2 different Sizes with @Media Query

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, media-queries

Tech used :  React and SCSS

Objective : print page A with size :1000px and page B with size: 288px.

Expected Outcome: Page A & B has size of 1000px by 1000px & 288px by 288px respectively when styled using @media print and printed using window.print().

Actual Outcome: Both Page A and B has size of 1000px by 1000px when styled using @media print and printed using window.print().

I have tried separating the .scss file and their class but the result is still the same. Here's my code when I combine the classes inside 1 .scss file.`

```
@mixin band($name) {
  @if $name == yellow {
    @media print {
        size: 1000px 1000px;
      background-color: $name;
    }
  } @else if $name == white {
    @media print {
      size: 288px 288px;
      background-color: $name;
    }
  } @else {
    font-size: 20px
  }
}

.band-white {
    @include band($name: white);
}

.band-black {
    @include band($name: yellow);
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "my code keep printing it" ? The code seems ok.

Comment: My code prints my band-white class in size: 1000px

Comment: I am not very familiar with the `@media print`, but if I am not wrong you should be able to see the styles only if you actually print the page. It is what you tried ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to print the page.